# (Error while running a command with SSH) command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option

Tags: bash, jenkins

Error Msg:

> command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option:

```
sh '''ssh -i ${rundeck_rsa_key} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o centos@xxxx.net "sudo su -c "sh ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh" rundeck"'''
```

Broken Down command (I just made the above command for your convenience)

```
sh '''ssh -i ${rundeck_rsa_key} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
      -o centos@xxxx.net "sudo su -c "sh ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh" servc"'''
```

I'm trying to

1. ssh into the server
2. change user to "servc"
3. execute xx.sh shell

I think there is a syntax error on `"sudo su -c "sh ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh" servc"`

Do you have any clue?? :D

Comment: Why is it all wrapped in a call to `sh`? By the way, if the remote `sudo` asks for a password, which I assume it will, you won't be able to enter it.

Comment: Have you tried simply `ssh -i ${rundeck_rsa_key} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o centos@xxxx.net "sh -c sudo ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh rundeck"`?  (`centos@xxx.net` must have either `sudo` or `su` privileges on `xxx.net` of which you need one (`sudo` or `su -c`), but not both)

Comment: @lurker no pw is required.

Comment: The error message tells me that one of your `ssh` options `-o` isn't right (they're configuration options). Aren't configuration options of the form `key=value`? In which case `centos@xxxx.net` would be an invalid configuration option. You haven't explained why you need `sh`.

Comment: @lurker I took out -o and showing me a different error. `user ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh` does not exist.

Comment: I just need to execute the xx.sh as "rundeck" user in the host.

Comment: I'm not so sure "just taking out the -o" is the right solution. Why did you do that? The whole command line has to make sense all together, option by option, argument by argument. What's the purpose of `centos@xxxx.net`? By removing `-o`, you changed it from an invalid configuration option, to an `ssh` command line argument after the option, so it must mean something.

Comment: I need to ssh into the server as centos user > then change my user to `rundeck` > execute a script.

Comment: `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o`,,, it's bypassing the host key checking. newly added Jenkins instance adds RSA private token in its instance and it caused an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest a double quoted string inside another without escaping the inner ones.

Try this:

```
sh '''ssh -i ${rundeck_rsa_key} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o centos@xxxx.net "sudo su -c \"sh ./home/centos/releases/xx.sh\" rundeck"'''
```

Comment: Also, if `rundeck_rsa_key` is a parameter the `'''` should be replaced with `"""`

Comment: Worked. Thank you.